# Match phone numbers with lengths between 8-16 digits, ignoring ()+-

Tags: regex

Consider the following:

```
+12 34 456 432
(12) 34 567 124
1234 56 78 90
(1234) 567 890
1234-567-890
1234 - 567 - 890
12 34 56 78
12-34-56-78
```

Assume these are all valid phone number structures

Can a regex be used to express: find at least 8 numbers,but not more than 16 and ignore spaces, round brackets, the plus symbol(once) and the minus.

My current working sample is a mess:

```
^([\+|\(]{1,2})?+(\d{2,4})+([ |-|\)]{1,2})?+(\d{2,3})+([ |-]{1})?+(\d{2,3})+([ |-]{1})?+(\d{2,3})?$
```

Even if phone number validation is recommended against. Is there not a simpler regex syntax for these things?

Comment: Maybe [`^\+?(?:[ ()-]*\d){8,16}$`](https://regex101.com/r/lM6wN6/2)?

Comment: @stribizhev I think, that one does it. The '?:' is some sort of lookahead isn't it?

Comment: Not a lookahead, just a non-capturing group. What language are you using for this task?

Comment: @stribizhev php and js. Not ajax because I would rather not make http requests for every check. The idea is to start the js validation after the first submit. That way I can mark the invalid fields and make suggestions on how to correct them. More importantly I can give feedback on wether their new input is valid or not.

Comment: I have added my answer that is basically working in both JS and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just account for the number of digits and ingore the `-`, `)`, `(` or spaces (allowing a `+` at the beginning), you can use the following regex:

```
^\+?(?:[ ()-]*\d){8,16}$
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\+?` - one or zero `+`
- `(?:[ ()-]*\d){8,16}` - 8 to 16 sequences of...

  - `[ ()-]*` - 0 or more `-`, `)`, `(` or a space characters
  - `\d` - a digit
- `$` - end of string

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM6wN6/2)

Answer (score 1):

This may ease your task.

First, remove everything that is not a number:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

You'll get this:

```
1234456432
1234567124
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
12345678
12345678
```

Then just check for length:

```
if(myString.length >= 0 && myString.length <=16)
// Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_replace fetch numbers only, check for the valid length

```
<?php       
$ph = "(12) 34 567 124";
$len = strlen(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $ph));
if($len >=8 && $len <=16)
    echo "Valid";
else 
    echo "Invalid";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't even think about it. Phone numbers are complicated. They are *hugely* complicated. Google has a decent library to handle phone numbers named libPhoneNumber.

And excuse me, but ignoring the "+" makes whatever you are doing totally, absolutely wrong. A plus is followed by the country code of some country, followed by a local phone number within that country (which needs to be parsed according to the rules of that country, and there are about 200). Without the "+", you have a phone number according to the local rules, and you need to find out which local rules apply. Which means your number can start with a code for dialing a foreign exchange instead of the "+", otherwise it is formatted according to local rules.

As a result, a number may be valid with the "+" and invalid without it or vice versa, and most likely refers to a different actual phone in totally different countries with or without the "+".

Comment: My group is limited to my own country and 1 or 2 neighbouring countries. I checked the formatting of these countries before I started this. What do you suggest?